# Can we create hashmap with dynamic key and dynamic value?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am creating a hashmap as follows:

```
HashMap <String,String> DtsFeed = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

My key is dynamic and the value is also dynamic.

```
DtsFeed.put(Request.getRequestId(), feedtype);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Both are String type

Comment: If both are String type use generics for that. HashMap<String,String> dtsFeed = new HashMap<String,String>();

Comment: What exactly is a "dynamic key" and a "dynamic value"?

Comment: What do you know about `HashMap`? It forbids changing key after entry addition (because changing key involves changing key's `hashCode()`). You can change key by that way: `map.put(newkey,map.remove(oldkey))` (i.e. remove old entry and then add new one), direct change of your key will break your HashMap. P.S. Strings are immutable in java, so your HashMap will contain all entries with old keys if you don't remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Your example work, but i suggest adding the generics although not required.

```
HashMap<Object,Object> DtsFeed = new HashMap<>();
DtsFeed.put(key, value);
Object got = DtsFeed.get(key);
```

Map.get() works always with plain objects regardless of the map definition.

But remember you have to cast the returned results from the map in order to use them. (Your solution is potentially dangerous/unsafe though)

You can also iterate over the entrySet()/keySet()

Comment: How do you get a value from the HashMap once it is inserted?

Answer (score 2):

If "dynamic key" means that the contents of the key changes while it is in the Map, then the answer is that you have to be very careful. Nothing good will happen if the key's `hashcode()` value changes while it is in the map. If you let this happen, then lookups using the key will fail to find the entry.

If you let some portion of the key change, but ensure that `equals()` and `hashcode()` don't change, then lookups will continue to work. I have never seen this implemented in practice.

What I have seen done often is to use an invariant part of the logical key as the actual key. For example, we might have a entity that represents a row in a database and contains an ID value that will not change. You would use the ID as the key in a map (e.g., `Map<Long, Value>` rather than `Map<Entity, Value>`).

This generally doesn't work:

```
Map<Entity, Value> map = new HashMap<>();
Entity entity = ...
Value value = ...
map.put(entity, value);
entity.setA(a);
Value willBeNull = map.get(entity);
```

This generally does work:

```
Map<Long, Value> map = new HashMap<>();
Entity entity = ...
Value value = ...
map.put(entity.getId(), value);
entity.setA(a);
Value willBeTheExpecteValue = map.get(entity.getId());
```

Comment: I've seen it and used it. As long as the objects identity is immutable (and `equals` and `hashcode` depend only on that) - it's perfectly fine. A common use case is for events that are identified by a timestamp and id (of actor or object).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the key and the value can both change? You might consider IdentityHashMap, which compares keys using their references rather than hashCode() and equals().

With IdentityHashMap, you can always retrieve the value associated with a key, even if the key can change state.